# Android AlertDialog not wraping content in KK

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I've created a multi purpose `AlertDialog` with one `WebView` in it. In all the devices that I've tested the dialog size is ok, that it, the height is always wrapping to the content. Unfortunately, on a Nexus 5 with 4.4.2 it's not showing properly. Sometimes it wraps, other don't.

Here is a screenshot of what I mean on a emulated Nexus 5.

[image]

Here is the `xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:background="@color/white"
              android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:ignore="DisableBaselineAlignment"
        android:id="@+id/alertdialog_title"
        android:weightSum="4">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">
        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:id="@+id/alertdialog_icon"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/info"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/alertdialog_titletext"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large"
                style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <View
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="@color/orange"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:ignore="DisableBaselineAlignment"
            android:id="@+id/alertdialog_content">
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the code for creating the `AlertDialog`

```
void showAlertDialog(String title, String message, final int messageType) {
    int padding = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.all_margins);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alertdialog, null);

    LinearLayout alertDialogContent = (LinearLayout) layout.findViewById(R.id.alertdialog_content);
    ImageView alertDialogIcon = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.alertdialog_icon);
    TextView alertDialogTitle = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.alertdialog_titletext);
    alertDialogTitle.setTypeface(fontBold);

    alertDialogIcon.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.info));
    alertDialogTitle.setText(title);
    alertDialogTitle.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.orange));

    WebView webview = new WebView(this);

    ScrollView scrollPane = new ScrollView(this);

    webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, message, "text/html", "utf-8", null);

    scrollPane.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
    scrollPane.addView(webview);
    alertDialogContent.addView(scrollPane);

    alertDialog.setView(layout);
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // Do something
        }
    });

    if (messageType == 0 || messageType == 3) {
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Do something
            }
        });
    }

    AlertDialog alert = alertDialog.create();
    alert.show();
    boolean tabletSize = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet);
    if (tabletSize) {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        alert.getWindow().setLayout((int) (metrics.widthPixels * 0.8), ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    }
}
```

What should I change to the `AlertDialog` always wraps it's content??

Answer (score 0):

It is the ScrollView default behaviour to get all the available space (that's my direct experience). I came across this *issue* some days ago, My solution was to measure the content of the ScrollView, and forcing its height. Something like (my situation was a `LinearLayout as direct child of the`ScrollView`that contains`TextView`s - pseudo-code)

```
 int height = 0;
 for (view I am going to add in the LL) {
    view.measure(0, 0);
    height += view.getMeasuredHeight();
 }
```

after this measure operation, I retrieve the root layout of the view hierarchy (`FrameLayout` in my case), and I forced its `params.height` to the calculated

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have some doubt's.
I've done this : `int height = 0;
        for (webview){
            webview.measure(0,0);
            height += webview.getMeasuredHeight();
        }` but that for statement it's not valid.
And I did not understand the last part. My root view is `layout`. How do I set its `params.height`?

Comment: for loop are for looping around a collection of elements. If you have just one element you don't need use it.

Comment: Thanks but sorry I do not understand